# Add text in Citation

Tags: citing

I want `[1, Eqns. (4)-(6)].` For that I have written

```
\cite{citekey} Eqns. (4)-(6).
```

But it generates `[1] Eqns. (4)-(6).` 
How to write `[1, Eqns. (4)-(6)].`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use `\cite[text]{citekey}` eg `\cite[Eqns.~(4)--(6)]{citekey}`

This creates, eg [1, Eqn 4--6].

One thing ye might watch with equations: these are numbered like `(4)--(6)` in the context of a chapter, but each chapter has its own run of numbers.  So an equation in chapter 2 might be referred to in chapter 3 as 2.6.

Comment: Great, It works.

Comment: \cite didn't work for me, \citep[description]{citekey} worked. Thanks for sharing!